# Control depth level of table of contents with org-mode and beamer

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I have the following in my org-mode file that I am exporting to beamer on the basis of [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html) simple template:

```
* Introduction
* More
** etc
* Still more
** Some a
** Some b
** Some c
```

However, my TOC only renders:

```
More
Still more
```

It neither renders the ** levels, nor the introduction, oddly.

I'm sure this setting exists, but I don't understand how to ask the TOC to render all ** levels.  What setting is controlling the level of TOC depth?

Answer (score 1):

[This seems to be a Beamer-level issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer), suggesting an Org Mode solution like so:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:1 num:t toc:nil \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+BEAMER_FRAME_TITLE: 1
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 1
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports both
#+OPTIONS: H:1
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \input{list-of-frames.tex}

* Outline
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
:END:
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\listofframes
\end{minipage}
* Main content
Hello Beamer!
```

where the input file has these contents:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\par}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the number of levels exported as headlines, which is controlled by `org-export-headline-levels`. Which value does this variable have?

The template you pointed to includes `#+OPTIONS: H:3`, are you sure you didn't alter that value?