# How can I get an outline in org-beamer export without changing the other frames?

Tags: org-export

I have this org-beamer example:

```
#+TITLE:      Example
#+LANGUAGE:   en
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+CREATOR: Emacs 26.3 (Org mode 9.1.9)
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %9BEAMER_envargs(Env Args) %4BEAMER_col(Col) %10BEAMER_extra(Extra)
#+OPTIONS:   num:t toc:t \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc

* Section

** Frame
   Pellentesque condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue ornare nulla, non luctus diam neque sit amet urna.

* Other Section

** Other Frame
   Nullam rutrum.

* Third Section

** Third Frame
   Pellentesque tristique imperdiet tortor.
```

It does what - almost. The "normal" pages look like this:
[image: Page like I want it]

But: the Outline is empty. I found that I can add an outline for the 2nd level org items with the option `#+OPTIONS: H:2`. With that option, I get an outline, but now the pages look like this:

[image: Missing Section]

Is there a way to get both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Joe Corneli's answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52198/control-depth-level-of-table-of-contents-with-org-mode-and-beamer), you can create an outline manually as
a list of your frames.

Create a file named `list-of-frames.tex` and edit your org file as follows:

`list-of-frames.tex:`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\par}%
}
```

`your-file.org:`

```
#+TITLE:      Example
#+LANGUAGE:   en
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+CREATOR: Emacs 26.3 (Org mode 9.1.9)
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+COLUMNS: %40ITEM %10BEAMER_env(Env) %9BEAMER_envargs(Env Args) %4BEAMER_col(Col) %10BEAMER_extra(Extra)
#+OPTIONS:   num:t toc:nil \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \input{list-of-frames.tex}

* Outline
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
:END:
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
\listofframes
\end{minipage}

* Section

** Frame
   Pellentesque condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue ornare nulla, non luctus diam neque sit amet urna.

* Other Section

** Other Frame
   Nullam rutrum.

* Third Section

** Third Frame
   Pellentesque tristique imperdiet tortor.
```